# How to get this date format "2022-06-18_21:31:17.568-07:00"

Tags: java, spring, datetime, simpledateformat

What is the format I need to do in order to get the date as like this `"2022-06-18_21:31:17.568-07:00"` in JAVA

```
yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
```

this is what I am trying to use but in this results like

```
2017-10-10_11:43:56.336+05
```

What I actually need is like `2022-06-18_21:31:17.568-07:00`

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Comment: Use `XXX` instead of `X` in your date format string to get it in the format `-07:00` instead of `-07`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use format like this `yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 
                 LocalDate.of( 2022 , 6 , 18 ) ,
                 LocalTime.of( 21 , 31 , 17 , 568_000_000 ) ,
                 ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) 
             ) 
             .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ) 
             .replace( "T" , "_" )
```

## ISO 8601

Your desired format nearly complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by the java.time classes. Replace the `T` in the middle of the standard format with the underscore you desired.

I would strongly recommend sticking with the standard, leaving the `T` in place, rather than invent your own format.

## java.time

Modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Avoid `SimpleDateFormat` as it is part of the troublesome old date-time classes. Now supplanted by java.time. In particular, the [`ZonedDateTime`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class here.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

The `toString` method in java.time classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default. In the case of `ZonedDateTime` that format is wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets, in addition to the offset-from-UTC.

> zdt.toString(): 2017-07-23T01:23:45.678-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## `DateTimeFormatter`

You could delete the appendage, if you insist, though it does provide valuable information.

Or you could generate the string using an alternate [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object, one built-in as a constant: [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ;
String output = z.format( f ) ;
```

If you insist, you can substitute for your underscore.

```
String modified = output.replace( "T" , "_" ) ;
```

> 2017-07-23_01:23:45.678-07:00